# MVC 5 Routing Adds Extra Slash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have an mvc 5 application on iis 7.5 which has a link which works properly when the application is referenced as an ip address, but not as a subdomain. so xxx.xxx.x.xx works while subdomain.mydomain.com fails. only this link, out of 9 or so on the page fails with this quirk.

all links work except one. when I hover over the link, the status bar shows http://subdomain.mydomain.com/Projects and when clicked lists projects when working - as seen in the routing config. i added the config item to force a route, but it fails.

it is defined in a shared layout as

```
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Projects")" @SiteMainMenuHelper.CurrentItem(ViewBag.SiteMainMenu, SiteMainMenu.Projects) data-icon="&#xe60f;">Projects</a></li>
```

the routing is

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        ////routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        // I created this first route to force the correct action but it does not work
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Projects",
            "Projects",
            new { controller = "Projects", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "user-activation",
            "user/activate/{token}",
            new { controller = "user", action = "activate" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "password-reset",
            "password/reset/{token}",
            new { controller = "password", action = "reset" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });


    }
```

however, when the subdomain is the host of the application, it lands on this url:
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/Projects/#/

but should be
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/Projects#/

I cannot figure out from where the extra / is coming. any leads or direction on how to fix would be appreciated - especially given that everything else works. i have looked in the RouteTable in the debugger and do not see any conflicts - but i may not be looking at the table correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow this problem is resolved. it may have been due to dns and iis configuration issues but no satisfactory explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The first route does not specify any place for the action, you should make it show

```
map.Routes(
   "Projects",
   "Projects/{action}",
   new { controller="Projects", action="Index"}
);
```

or...

```
map.Routes(
   "Projects",
   "Projects",
   new {controller="Projects", action = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```